# Converting tiff file (DEM) into XYZ file with FME?

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff, fme-form, xyz

I want to convert a tiff file (DEM) into an XYZ file with FME.  I have tried using the sa - sample tool in ArcGIS and it took 19 hours to accomplish 9% of the task.  I saw a post by Mark Ireland that mentioned using FME to accomplish this task much faster.  Here is an image of the post:
[image: This is the solution posted by Mark Ireland]

This looks relatively simple, however I am relatively inexperienced with FME and was wondering anyone can help decipher how to accomplish this task by looking at the FME diagram he posted.

Comment: Download FME and use the Workspace (FME Desktop) drag&drop your file (tiff) in and type in the workspace Geometry and your see a list appear onscreen then connect them together using the arrows. This video shows the method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HfiQI7ZJFs

Comment: I put together a quick demo movie of how I created that workspace. Very simple. Only takes a couple of minutes. See: http://screencast.com/t/FBRrnhTLrhRm